# OpenStack Horizon RBAC setting custom permissions

Tags: permissions, openstack, rbac, keystone, openstack-horizon

I'm working on customizing Horizon. My goal is to, not only limit access to certain aspects of the dashboard, but also remove these components from the dashboard depending on the user role. So I'm not sure if this is even the right direction to be heading.

I'm trying to understand where it defines permissions, for example on some given Horizon component I can add:

`permissions = list(getattr(instances_panel, 'permissions', []))
permissions.append('openstack.roles.admin')
instances_panel.permissions = tuple(permissions)`

My question is where are these roles defined? I assume in keystone, and how, if possible, can I reference custom roles for example:

`permissions.append('keystone.roles.my_custom_role')`

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Try this:

`permissions.append('openstack.roles.my_custom_role')`

Comment: I format the code for you, but a little more explanation of the answer would be great.